# How to paste like cat in R

Tags: r

I have vector  `A = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')`, and I want to glue all of these. Like, 'abcde'.

```
 paste(A)
```

Didn't work.

```
 cat(A)
```

worked, but cat is not a vector making function, rather just for printing.
I mean, I can't use cat() like

```
 A<-cat(A)
```

this way. Neither

```
 A<- as.factor(cat(A))
```

What should I do?

Comment: `paste(letters[1:5], collapse = '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```r
> paste(A, collapse = "")
[1] "abcde"
```